npm run build is failing due to typescript or lodash uncompatibility
typescript version: 4.5.2 
lodash version: 4.17.21
npm run build
tsc && react-scripts build


node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1026:46 - error TS1005: '?' expected.
1026         : K extends `${infer N extends number}` ? T[N] <br/>
                                                  ~
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1031:46 - error TS1005: '?' expected.
1031         : K extends `${infer N extends number}` ? T[N] <br/>
                                                  ~
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1041:46 - error TS1005: '?' expected.
1041         : K extends `${infer N extends number}` <br/>
                                                  ~


Found 3 errors.


There is an issue opened for @types/lodash. The only suggested fix at this moment - to use @types/lodash@4.17.5

After changing the version of lodash got new error for ansi-regex lib.
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102
throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath);
^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js
require() of /node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js from node_modules/renderkid/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.

Y suddenly getting this issue, we didn't changed our build configuration recently

Use lodash version 4.17.5 works for me.
I am using typescript version 4.6.4 and lodash version 4.17.5.
Uninstall the current version (4.17.6) and reinstall 4.17.5 version
npm uninstall @types/lodash
npm install @types/lodash@4.17.5
Then, the ng build should work

try this
"@types/lodash": "4.14.168"
Finally ,It works like a charm (   "typescript": "4.1.5")

yes, think approach works

I faced the exact same issue.
Two problems I have:

Lodash below version 4.17.20 has a critical security issue. So, downgrading is not an option.
Also, I can't update typescript to version 5 because of some old modules in my project...

My solution (=compromise) was to update Typescript to version 4.7.4 and the error disappeared.

Upgrade typescript to v5+.
Apart from this, if you're using any bundlers (e.g., Rollup, Webpack), don't forget to upgrade their TypeScript-related packages as well.
I had to upgrade rollup-plugin-ts.

The solution which worked for him.

typescript version at 4.7.2.
Added new dependency of @types/lodash at 4.17.5 version.

